# spice representation for mechanical problems

Tags: spice, ltspice

As a mechanical engineer, for my work, I need to compute some displacements which are represented as a summation of frequency dependent admittances on a structural system and I would like to use this summation representation in SPICE to find the input output behaviour of my system.

This looks like an extension of 2-port network theory(which I am reading about at the moment) to a system with N ports actually, I believe(since I do not have the proper background.).

I read that SPICE generates netlist for the circuits and these can be directly used for the simulations.

I was wondering if that is possible to generate, somehow, automatically the netlist of this N port system which is an approximation of the input output relation of the modelled structural system? I could make it for a two port system where there are really 2 inputs and 2 outputs already but my goal is to transfer my sum of admittances to an N port network representation where N could be an arbitrary number, 12 in this case, which represents the number of displacements and forces in a generic structural representation.

So my goal is to accomplish this for a 12 port network. But as the port numbers increase, the connections are becoming more complex. Is there a source that could guide me on this matter?

Answer (score 2):

One option is to  convert the mechanical system to an electrical analogue, and then simulate the circuit.  Example at http://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/Analogs/ElectricalMechanicalAnalogs.html

Ofcourse, the grunt approach is just to work out your diffeqs and numerically solve with matlab or octave.